# Where can I find the price list for Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

The Google API Console lists 500,000 / day as the "Courtesy limit", and provides a form allowing one to request more.

My assumption is that there will be a cost attached to a higher request limit; similar to the [Google Maps pricing](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing)

Where can I find the price list for the Google Drive API?

Comment: As of 2022 the answer can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no extra charge for more quota for the Google Drive API. It will be granted as long as you are making a reasonable request.

Big apps (e.g. those that make lots of requests) are good for Google Drive, and Google encourages them.

Comment: This is very wrong. Google places a limit on Drive requests (currently 500,000 per day) and will prevent apps from accessing this service once this limit has been reached. I have seen these limits reached by Drive extension apps that integrate online. While Google wants developers to use their service, they are not going to leave the gates open and let anyone just hog up the bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. Google will grant all reasonable requests to increase this quota, and at no cost to you. You just need to ask for more.

Comment: I can see there are limits to Google sheets API usage- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits I am getting error beyond that limits. For increasing the limit it is asking for creating a billing account.

Answer (score 7):

Google Cloud Console is updated, strangely it took me a while to find API Quotas under few layers...
Just in case if you need the direct link, here it is:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas

Comment: the link was dead.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar concern. [Google Cloud Platform Services](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) do have a price list, since [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) doesn't. Updated quota usage is limited to 1.000.000.000 requests/day, which can be raised by applying more quota usage form to Google.

No payment needed.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone was looking for the quota as of October 2015,

- Log into your Google Developer Console.
- Go to API's & auth > APIs.
- Click on Drive API and then the Quotas tab.

Currently the free quota is set at 1,000,000,000 requests/day so unless you are doing something extraordinary this should be enough for most anyone I would think.