# Building an app that connects to Google API

Tags: web-applications, google-drive-api

I am building a web-based app that I want users to connect to THEIR shared drive accounts, so they can move files into our app. They have to put thier credentials in, then Google Drive accepts, connects and open their drive so files can be moved. I was told by some developers that will cost money and they need a credit card so Google can bill me. I am confused on why WE would get charges when the User of our app is using THIER google drive account.  Can anyone provide some clarification to this?

Comment: Hi Google drive api is free upto about 500,000 hit a day This answer may help you all the best Paul https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159696/1123335

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find the price list for Google Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156781/where-can-i-find-the-price-list-for-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*There is no inherent charge that you will incur simply for building an application that uses the Google Drive API.*

#### More Information:

The G Suite APIs are free to use as long as you have a Google Account, though depending on the usage of the applications there are quotas and limits that you will have to bear in mind. [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) has its own quotas and limits if your web application is to be written and deployed on Google cloud, though otherwise you can see the API quotas and limits for your application at the [Google API Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

If your client needs quota above that which is free to use, then the project should be created in their developer dashboard with the correct billing settings charged to them, though this is not a Stack Overflow matter and should be discussed with your client if needs be.

#### References:

- [G Suite Admin Help - Monitor API Quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en)
- [Google Cloud Pricing Plans | G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html)
- [Google Apps Script - Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)
- [Google APIs Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)