# Google Drive API, Cost of increasing the limit of quotas, "Queries per 100 seconds per user" and "Queries per 100 seconds"

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm planning to request increasing the Google Drive API's quotas limit of "Queries per 100 seconds per user" from 10,000 to 10,000,000 drastically, because our application uses a lot of Google Drive accessing.
I'm wondering whether;
1. increasing the quota takes any costs or not
2. using this api takes any costs or not

I found the link below that users disccusses about it.
[Where can I find the price list for Google Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156781/where-can-i-find-the-price-list-for-google-drive-api)

However, it is not cleared that  we can increase and use free charge or not.

Could you please give me the information about it?

Answer (score 1):

#### As per Drive API v3 documentation.

You can request an increase in quota; you do need a billing account.
You have to make the request first, and then they will answer granting it or not, there is no public price list.

For a direct link to the quotas section in your console, follow [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas)

also, it is worth reading through [these common errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#quota) and how to get around them.