# FFMPEG using Google Drive API instead of Shared URL

Tags: ffmpeg, google-drive-api

We are using FFMPEG to stream a Google Drive URL into a node application.

Is there an FFMPEG method or library we can use to stream to FFMPEG using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) instead of using the standard public shared URL?

At the moment using the URL works fine if the file size is <100mb but with bigger files we get an error:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=fileId: Invalid data found when processing input
```

This is because we reach the pesky gDrive virus roadblock page:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I understood that your file is publicly shared. In this case, when the file size becomes large, the endpoint of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=fileId` is required to be processed with 2 steps. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859) This has already been also mentioned in your question.

In this answer, in order to avoid this, I would like to propose to use the method of "Files: get" in Drive API and the API key. When Drive API and API key is used for the publicly shared file, no 2 step flow is required, and it can use it by changing only the URL.

#### Endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={your API key}
```

- For example, as a test, when you use curl command, you can use `curl "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={your API key}"`.

#### References:

- [Download a file stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Using API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

Comment: Nice, thanks.  If we use this method do we get charged for data transfer of files downloaded using this API key?  I'm hoping not because the file is publicly shared from a personal Drive and not downloaded from our own Google storage? Would be good to clarify.

Comment: @Marcus Thank you for replying. Drive API can be used by free of charge. When the usage limit exceeded, an error occurs. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors) I think that these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14156781 https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311969

Comment: Apparently this method will be deprecated at some point? https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api  Would you be able to append your answer with the HTTP version of the same possibly?

Comment: @Marcus In your URL, the query of `access_token` will be deprecated. In your case, the API key is used for the public content. In this case, the API key can be continue to be used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415475